# Passing the execution of a program to another window manager

Tags: linux, xserver, x11, xmonad

I am currently using Arch Linux and Xmonad, but it doesn't seem to play all that well with my OpenGL projects for my college course. Currently, I am simply switching to another X server running Openbox and doing all my work in there if I know I am going to be using OpenGL, but I then lose all of the nice tiling features of Xmonad.

Considering that I am the user logged into both X servers, is there a way for me to pass the execution of the OpenGL program to the Openbox X server from the Xmonad X server? That way, all I would need the Openbox X server for is running the OpenGL program correctly.

Comment: try `echo $DISPLAY` in a terminal for each WM. then try invoking a program `DISPLAY=:1 program`, where 1 is the *other* display.

Comment: you might also be interested `chvt` http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_chvt.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your WM, the environment variable `$DISPLAY` indentifies the display. Different X11 instances will have different `$DISPLAY` variables.

To find out your current `$DISPLAY`:

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

which, for example, prints `:0`.

Now you can start a program for a specific display:

```
DISPLAY=":1" someprogram
```

if security allows it (refer to, e.g., `man xhost`), the program will open on the specified X11 display.